# How can I use Apache Sedona in Code Repositories?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I need expanded geospatial functions that are not in Foundry's base geospatial functions library, so I am trying to add the `st_functions` library from Sedona Spark. Code repo recognizes the function package as when you hover over the function `ST_ISValid()` with your mouse, it produces a callout detailing what the function does. In addition, I know the `st_functions` are stored in this object.

I tried attaching the following code to my `build.gradle` file as outlined [here](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/geospatial/vector_data_in_transforms/#installation):

```
dependencies {
    condaJars "org.apache.sedona:sedona-python-adapter-3.0_2.12:1.2.1-incubating"
    condaJars "org.apache.sedona:sedona-sql-3.0_2.12:1.2.1-incubating"
    condaJars "org.apache.sedona:sedona-core-3.0_2.12:1.2.1-incubating"
    condaJars "org.datasyslab:geotools-wrapper:geotools-24.0"
}
```

And followed the rest of the instructions. But I am still getting `Java classpath reference error` when I try to use Sedona geospatial functions.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to download the apache-sedona into the Code Repository Libraries.
[image]

Then check out what version of Sedona you are using. This should match the code block you inserted into your `build.gradle` file. For instance, in the screenshot below the version is `1.3.1` so I need to update the code block to match.
[image]

```
dependencies {
    condaJars "org.apache.sedona:sedona-python-adapter-3.0_2.12:1.3.1-incubating"
    condaJars "org.apache.sedona:sedona-sql-3.0_2.12:1.3.1-incubating"
    condaJars "org.apache.sedona:sedona-core-3.0_2.12:1.3.1-incubating"
    condaJars "org.datasyslab:geotools-wrapper:geotools-24.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use st_functions in `F.expr("")` with geospatial-tools imported:

```
F.expr("ST_IsValid(geometry)")
```